# Angular 2 - router implementation non linear

Tags: angular

I came across something wicked in angular router, routing definition from 1st level to 2nd level is not the same as from 2nd level to 3rd level

I have a route /a/b that worked fine

but /a/b/c was not working (Cannot match any routes error)

after digging, I found this example that stated the route of the 3rd level should be implemented on the 2nd level module instead of following the same logic...once I moved the routes of my 3rd level in the 2nd level module, it worked

(in the example below they dont use a submodule, but I do, and I relate to it in my 2nd level module, so it should work, ....)

```
const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        children: [ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< why here and not in a  submodule with his own routing ????
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: CrisisDetailComponent,
            canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
            resolve: {
              crisis: CrisisDetailResolver
            }
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

while the app component routing let the children define their own routes

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'compose',
    component: ComposeMessageComponent,
    outlet: 'popup'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    loadChildren: 'app/crisis-center/crisis-center.module#CrisisCenterModule',
    data: { preload: true }
  },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

can someone tell me why it is that way ?
am I missing something ?

Comment: _but /a/b/c was not working (Cannot match any routes error)_ - what URL are you navigating to?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I couldn't get the question actually? What are you expecting from all this sub-routing?

Comment: the question is really clear, if you ever tried to do a 3rd level routing module, you'll encounter the issue, nothing fancy here...anybody else ?

Comment: to summarize : why do the nested children work in the example above instead of having each children array in his own respective module

Comment: @Maximus /a/b/c obviously and it works, but the children routes have to be in the same routing module which does not make any sens

Comment: the whole seriousness of angular support sumarized here